# Discord.js: Parameters with dynamic command handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to write a Discord bot with [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/). I used the [official guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/dynamic-commands.html#how-it-works) to set up dynamic command handling in my index.js file. You can read the command handler here:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const lobby = require('./scripts/lobby');
const context = require('./context');
const { token, prefix } = require('./context');

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
        client.commands.get(command).execute(
            message, 
            args, 
            client,
            lobby,
            context
        );
    
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('There was an error executing that command.');
    }
});
```

The commands are stored as a JavaScript module in seperate files. A simple example would be the ping command:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Ping!',
    execute(message, context) {
        console.log(context.activeLang.ping[0]);
    },
};
```

When I log `console.log(context.activeLang.ping[0])` to the console in my index.js file, it logs the correct value. When I do so in my ping module, node crashes with the following TypeError:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'ping' of undefined`

I don't understand why my command script apparently does not access context.js correctly. If anybody has a recommendation on how to solve this issue, i'd be super grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now `context` is actually filling the `args` argument. Parameter names, in this case `message` and `context` are simply placeholders for the corresponding argument. Their value is not calculated by their name, rather the order they appear.

---

```js
// example:

// this function, command, will trigger the given 
// function and pass the argument b (1)
function command(func) {
  var b = 1
  func(b)
};

command((a, b, c) => {

  // even though the arguments name was b, it's value is still tied to a
  console.log(a)
});
```

Even though your parameter was *named* `context`, it was actually tied to `args`.

Use:

```js
execute(message, args, client, lobby, context)
```

instead so everything will be tied to the right parameter.

---

[`arguments` info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)